# onCreate() method is triggered when I use my device gallery

Tags: android, android-activity, image-uploading, oncreate, onresume

I'm trying to create an application where there is a need of uploading images from my mobile. In this case, when I open my Gallery and choose a image and come back to my application, onCreate() is called again due to which the TextView, EditText and the booleans which I've used earlier are cleared.

Can you please help me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Are you asking if you can maintain the states of your TextView, EditText and other variables associated with your activity?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to have...@PeonProgrammer

Comment: can you show me the onCreate method in your activity that contains the TextView, Edit Text and boolean ? Maybe your savedInstance state is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is getting destroyed due to memory issue you might be doing  some bitmap op or something check it out also try adding large heap=true in manifest